# Insertar variables que vienen por GET y POST

Tags: php, http

Cordial saludo.
Por favor quien podría ayudarme con lo siguiente, tengo un formulario de inserción el cual trae por GET el id del alumno, es decir hay una fila que contiene los datos de un alumno y por medio de un enlace abro un formulario para ingresar los familiares de ese alumno, el inconveniente está en que el ID que viene por GET no lo inserta en la nueva tabla a la cuál voy afectar.

Este es el código del formulario para digitar los datos y enviar:

```
$consulta=($_GET['id']);
//echo $consulta;
include 'conexion.php';
$sentencia="SELECT * FROM tbl_alumnos WHERE id_alumno='".$_GET['id']."' "; 
$resultado=$mbd->prepare($sentencia) or die ("Error al consultar el Alumno".mysqli_error($mbd));
$resultado->execute();
$fila=$resultado->fetchAll();

?>

<?php
foreach($fila as $alumnos): ?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>IE | Industrial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="container">

      <form action="insertar_acudiente.php" method="post">

        <h2>Acudiente</h2>
       <h3> <div align="center">
          <input type="hidden" name="id_alumno" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']?>">
          <?php echo "Alumno ".$alumnos['nombres']; ?><br>
        </div></h3>
        <img src="images/actualizar.fw.png">

        <label>Papá</label><input type="checkbox" REQUIRED name="papa">
        <label>Mamá</label><input type="checkbox" REQUIRED name="mama">
        <label>Abuelo</label><input type="checkbox" REQUIRED name="abuelo">
        <label>Abuela</label><input type="checkbox" REQUIRED name="abuela">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="hermanos" placeholder="Total hermanos">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="otros" placeholder="Otros">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="matriculo" placeholder="Quien matriculo">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="totalconvive" placeholder="Total con quien vive">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="aportes" placeholder="Aportes">

        <input type="submit" value="REGISTRAR">
        <?php
      endforeach
      ?>
    </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Este es el código del archivo insertar_acudiente.php que realiza el insert sql en el cuál me aparecen estos errores:

**Notice**: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\login1\sistema\insertar_acudiente.php on line 5

**Notice**: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\login1\sistema\insertar_acudiente.php on line 10

```
    //$id=($_GET['id']);

    NuevoAcudiente($_GET['id'], $_POST['papa'], $_POST['mama'], $_POST['abuelo'], $_POST['abuela'], $_POST['hermanos'], $_POST['otros'], $_POST['matriculo'], $_POST['totalconvive'], $_POST['aportes']);

    function NuevoAcudiente($id, $papa, $mama, $abuelo, $abuela, $hermanos, $otros, $matriculo, $totalconvive, $aportes)
    {
        include 'conexion.php';
        $sentencia="INSERT INTO tbl_acudiente (id_alumno, papa, mama, abuelo, abuela, hermanos, otros, matriculo, totalconvive, aportes) VALUES ('".$_GET['id']."', '".$papa."', '".$mama."', '".$abuelo."', '".$abuela."', '".$hermanos."', '".$otros."', '".$matriculo."', '".$totalconvive."','".$aportes."')";
        $mbd->query($sentencia) or die ("Error al ingresar los datos".mysqli_error($conexion));
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Datos familiares ingresados correctamente");
    //window.location.href='index.php';
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás confundiendo dos momentos distintos en los que se invoca tu *script*.

Primero, **algo de concepto**: Cada vez que se invoca al servidor web, a través del protocolo HTTP, se hace con un único verbo o [método de petición](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods).

Los verbos más comunes son `GET` y `POST`, pero también existen otros, `HEAD`, `PUT` y `DELETE` se han puesto *de moda* por los servicios REST.

Entonces, cuando se ejecuta tu *script*, solamente uno de los vectores `$_GET` o `$_POST` tendrá información, nunca ambos.

El hecho de que una llamada anterior se haya realizado con un `$_GET` que traía cierto parámetro, por ejemplo, el `ID` del alumno es algo que no puedes saber durante la llamada a `$_POST`. Esto se debe a que `HTTP` es un [protocolo sin estado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_sin_estado). Es algo que no puedes olvidar mientras desarrollas para la web.

Dicho esto, hay varias técnicas que se utilizan para lograr *recordar* información entre llamadas, la más adecuada para tu caso me parece que es:

Cuando tu script es invocado mediante `GET`, al construir el formulario, basta con **incluir el ID del alumno** como un `input` de este, utilizando el tipo **`hidden`**, de manera que no es visible ni editable por el usuario, pero en cambio forma parte de la llamada mediante `POST`, algo así:

```
<input type="hidden" id="IdAlumno" name="IdAlumno" value="12345">
```

De esta forma, puedes tener acceso regular a su valor mediante `$_POST['IdAlumno']`

Finalmente, si quieres saber con que método de petición fue invocado tu script, puedes utilizar  [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`](https://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // …
}
```

Comment: Mil gracias por tu orientación, estaba confundido en algo tan elemental, ya está corregido!!

Comment: Excelente @Sergio, me alegra ser de ayuda. Un saludo. ;)